# call several callback function in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy and I have several problems:

first problem: I put start_requests in a loop but the function is not started from each iteration

second problem: I need to call different callback related to the start_urls given by the loop, but I can't give a dynamic name for the callback. I would like to put callback=parse_i and i come from the loop above.

```
liste [[liste1],[liste2],[liste3]]

for i in range (0, 2):
    start_urls = liste[i]

    def start_requests(self):
        #print(self.start_urls)
        for u in self.start_urls:
            try:
                req = requests.get(u)
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                print("Connection refused")
            if req.status_code != 200:

                print("Request failed, status code is :", req.status_code)
                continue
            yield scrapy.Request(u, callback=self.parse, meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True}, dont_filter=False)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to call different callback related to the `start_urls` given by the loop, but I can't give a dynamic name for the callback. I would like to put `callback=parse_i` and `i` come from the loop above.

The callback attribute just needs to be a callable, so you can use `getattr` just like normal:

```
my_callback = getattr(self, 'parse_{}'.format(i))
yield Request(u, callback=my_callback)
```

---

Separately, while you didn't ask this, it is highly unusual to make a URL call from within `start_requests` since (a) that's why one would use Scrapy to begin with, to deal with all that non-200 stuff and (b) doing so with `requests` will not honor any of the throttling, proxy, user-agent, resumption, or host of other knobs over which one would wish to influence a scraping job.